# New line in the input area giving error in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Just learning about PHP and wordpress and getting some problem.Here is my use-case.
I have a text area like

```
<textarea id='contact-message' class='contact-input' name='message' cols='40' rows='4' tabindex='1004'></textarea>
```

and user can input text in this area.everything is working fine but if user while typing the message hit the `"Enter Key"` it will start on the new line in text area and this new line is giving me the following exception when i am trying to submit the form

When user submitting the form i am creating a URL String and passing it to a java script function to submit by ajax call.This is my

### PHP code

```
$input = "u_email=".$email;
$input .= "&u_subject=" .$subject . "&u_message=" .$message .  "&u_ip=" . $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] ."&u_name=" .$name;
echo "<script>rtf_submit('$baseURL','$input');</script>";
```

### JS Code

```
 function rtf_submit(url,requestURL){
}
```

This was the submitted URL being created by above PHP code

```
u_email=dud@dud.com&u_subject=&u_message=Hello World&u_ip=127.0.0.1&u_name=hello
```

and this is the exception i am getting

```
Error: unterminated string literal
Line: 0, Column: 83
Source Code:
rtf_submit('http://localhost/blog/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/user_feedback/','u_email=dud@dud.com&u_subject=&u_message=Hello
```

I press enter key after typing `Hello` and this space/new line is being not handled properly by java-script code.

Is there any way i can handle this at PHP side to avoid such cases or need to be done at java-script?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On server side, you can try using `htmlentities`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to encode your form inputs so they'll be treated properly by the browser (or Javascript code, in this case). You can do this in Javascript or PHP - for some information on doing it in Javascript, take a look at [this page](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/).